# Evitar o uso de loop 'explícito', encontrar/editar array com o valor desejado

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
$users = array(
    array(
        'id' => 17,
        'name' => 'Miguel'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 23,
        'name' => 'Vera'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 39,
        'name' => 'Sara'
    )
);
```

A minha questão é: dá para editar (acrescentar/editar/apagar), os valores de um dos arrays com base num dos seus valores sem usar o `for/foreach/while`?

Por exemplo: gostaria de acrescentar uma chave/valor ao array cujo id é 23, de maneira a ficar:

```
...
array(
    'id' => 23,
    'name' => 'Vera',
    'loggedin' => true
),
...
```

Estive a dar uma olhadela [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter) e nas funções de que falam mas não acho (pelo menos eu não consegui implementar) que seja alguma delas.

Comment: Acredito que teria que ter um loop pelo menos no primeiro array, daí no segundo você localiza a chave pela função `array_key_exists`. Foreach($users as $arr => $valor) { if array_key_exists('23', $arr) { <faz o que é necessário> }}

Comment: Sim isso eu sei fazer, queria saber (por curiosidade) se dava para fazer sem... Mas obgado @RodrigoTognin. PS: Nem era preciso isso, bastava: `foreach($users as $arr => $valor) { if($valor['id'] == 23) { <faz o que é necessário> }}`

Comment: Tem a função `array_push` , ela aceita inserir item no final de um array mas não deixa indicar a chave, como você está querendo...

Comment: Tente assim: `$users[2]['loggedin'] = 'true';`

Comment: Sim eu sei @RodrigoTognin. Mas e se eu não souber a chave principal? Se eu não souber que este array se encontra no index `1`... Lembre-se que começa a contar do 0 :P

Comment: Verdade... fui me lembrar só agora que inicia-se no 0... Mas então, se não souber a chave aí complica, pois não tem como acessar o array do usuário específico sem saber. Ou guarda um outro array só com as chaves como índices, mas isso seria redundância. Eu prefiro usar um `foreach` mesmo, rsrsrs

Comment: Sim eu também lol, provavelmente mesmo que haja uma maneira alternativa num projeto real provavelmente continuava a fazer isso dentro de um loop... É só por curiosidade mesmo

Comment: Uma "plus" na sua pergunta @miguel seria: Oque é mais rápido? Pensando em um array com 1000 registros por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, eu sei, mas como digo em cima é por motivos apenas didáticos (curiosidade), provavelmente vou continuar a fazer como sempre fiz, com um loop @AndreiCoelho

Comment: @miguel com certeza loop é muito mais fácil de aplicar. Mas digo qual seria mais rápido de rodar? Na aplicação mesmo.

Comment: Era uma questão de testar... Nada demais, tendo as duas alternativas rastrear o tempo de execução de cada uma delas e comparar @AndreiCoelho

Comment: Como faz isso? @miguel

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43208/discussion-between-miguel-and-andrei-coelho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do modo como está esse array é totalmente possível. O problema é que quanto mais dimenções , ou melhor,  quanto mais multidimensional o array se torna, mais complicado e mais complexo o código fica, trazendo a necessidade de loopings.

Neste caso em específico fica fácil veja:

```
// abaixo usei o array_search para pesquisar a chave primária do array onde na sua coluna id contenha o valor setado.

// com isso podemos fazer qualquer modificação:

$users = array(
  array(
    'id' => 17,
    'name' => 'Miguel'
),
array(
    'id' => 23,
    'name' => 'Vera'
),
array(
    'id' => 39,
    'name' => 'Sara'
)
);

// exemplo de inserção

$local = array_search(23, array_column($users, 'id'));

$users[$local]['loggedin'] = true;


// exemplo de edição

$local = array_search(17, array_column($users, 'id'));

$users[$local]['name'] = "Miguelito";


// exemplo para deletar

$local = array_search(39, array_column($users, 'id'));

unset($users[$local]['name']);

print_r($users);

?>
```

Só para deixar claro, esse código é apenas para aprendizado, como foi citado pelo @miguel. Fiz uns testes com ajuda dele para saber qual das duas aplicações executam mais rápido e o loop `for` em todos os testes executou 2x mais rápido.

Comment: Totalmente impossível?! Mas você conseguiu... Era isso mesmo queria, fazer isso sem fazer um `loop` explicitamente. Obgado Andrei

Comment: Obrigado pelo desafio @miguel! na verdade, eu aprendi bastante e me questionei sobre mais coisas.

Comment: Isso deu perfeitamente para responder à minha questão. Mas se gosta de desafios, tenho outro: Isto só se aplica à primeira ocorrência do `id = 23` se tivermos mais ids que sejam 23 e quisessemos editar em todos? Como faria? Sem usar na mesma loops.

Comment: Boa idéia @miguel vou pensar em como fazer

Comment: Eu vi a sua mensagem no chat mas já dava para responder... Sim essa é a maneira de medir o tempo de execução de num programa